# Remove multiple keys from jsonb column in one statement

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to remove multiple keys from a `jsonb` column.

I've managed to get it to delete a single key with the following statement:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET data_column = data_column #- '{attr_1}'
WHERE type = 'type_a'
```

I understand thats a path so I can't do:
`#- '{attr_1,attr_2}`

Based on the docs I should be able to also do `- 'attr_1'` but that didn't work otherwise I'd attempt to try `- 'attr_1,attr2'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That should be as simple as applying the `#-` operator multiple times:

```
SELECT '{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }'::jsonb #- '{a}' #- '{b}';

 ?column? 
----------
 {"c": 3}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Well that seems obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: @Laurenz Albe what about removing an array from keys generated by a subquery?

Comment: @Sardothien Should be the same. Perhaps ask a new question.

Answer (score 21):

Or the minus operator once (but using a text array):

```
SELECT '{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }'::jsonb - '{a,b}'::text[];
 ?column? 
----------
 {"c": 3}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hey @Gerard do you know what version this was introduced, I get `operator does not exist: jsonb - text[]` when I try to execute something similar?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen, it was introduced in Postgre 10 - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html.

Answer (score 13):

If you need to remove multiple non-nested keys you can use `-` operator:

```sql
SELECT '{ "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }'::jsonb - ARRAY['a', 'b'];
```

Answer (score 5):

Multiple usages of the minus operator, like;

```
UPDATE table_a
SET data_column = data_column - 'attr_1'- 'attr_2'- 'attr_3'
WHERE type = 'type_a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_a
SET data_column = data_column - 'attr_1'
WHERE type = 'type_a';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

we wanted to remove the `template_approval_type` from the `setting` of our table `templates`. `setting` was a JSONb column.

query was as easy as:

```
UPDATE templates SET setting = setting::jsonb #- '{template_approval_type}'
```